# Integrate volume of solid evolving around $y=-1$

Tags: integration, volume

I need some help with the working and solution to this volume and integration problem. I don't really have a starting point.

The region bounded by $y=-1$, $y=e^{2x}$, $x=0$ and $x=2$ is revolved about the line 
$y=-1$. Find the volume of the resulting solid.

Answer (score 1):

Use the disk method to integrate over $x$. For any $x$ within $[0,2]$, the disk radius is $e^{2x}+1$.

Thus, the volume integral is,

$$V=\pi \int_0^2 (e^{2x}+1)^2dx$$
$$=\pi \int_0^2 (e^{4x}+2e^{2x}+1)dx$$
$$=\pi \left(\frac14( e^{8}-1)+(e^{4}-1)+2\right)$$
$$=\frac\pi4 \left( e^{8}+4e^{4}+3\right)$$

Comment: Are you able to work out the integral and add the results to an answer? I'm after full working.

Comment: @user694587 - Sure, added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Do a change of variables so that you are revolving the solid about the line $y=0$, IE the x-axis, instead.